# Correct handling of Ajax.BeginForm OnSuccess

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an area of code which calls the method 'SaveNewSoftware'. This method returns true if the software doesn't exist, and false if it finds that software with the same name is already present. My issue is that even if the server call returns false, onsuccess still fires.

How can I handle the data the returned data so that OnSuccess only fires if true is returned? (I did think about using OnError, but my understanding of that is it only fires if an exception occurs).

EDIT: Here's the code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveNewSoftware", "Software", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "environmentcontent", HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "CloseModal('#myModalWindowstack1');AddAlert('#alertarea','New Software Has Been Added!');" },
```

Please excuse my lack of knowledge when it comes to Ajax; I'm still very new to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
onSuccess: function(data) {
    if (data === 'true') {
        myOnSuccess(data);
    }
}, ...

function myOnSuccess(data) {
    // do a thing
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use that with Ajax.BeginForm? (See my latest edit). If that would work with the format we're using that would be ideal

Comment: Gave this a try the next day and it worked a treat! Thank you!